# NavigationController doesn't see right bar button item

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand presentation view controllers by allowing the user to add new outcomes of a fortune telling app. When the user taps on "Add New Outcome" on the top right of the navigation bar a new view controller pops up and this is where the user can enter a new outcome. I'm trying to add a done button to the top right of the presentation controller but I'm getting an error saying `Value of type 'UINavigationController?' has no member 'rightBarButtonItem'`.

I thought it was because of referencing the topViewController was the problem but I'm doing this all in 1 ViewController.

```
@IBAction func actionButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddNewOptionController")
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popover : UIPopoverPresentationController = viewController.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.barButtonItem = sender
    popover.delegate = self
    present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .fullScreen
}

func presentationController(_ controller: UIPresentationController, viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle style: UIModalPresentationStyle) -> UIViewController? {
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller.presentedViewController)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissViewController))
//error below
     navigationController.topViewController?.navigationController.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton
    return navigationController
}

func dismissViewController() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
navigationController.topViewController?.navigationController.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton
```

Try:

```
navigationController.topViewController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton
```

Comment: Navigation items like the right bar button item are specific to each view controller in the navigation controller stack.  So you can't set them in the navigation controller itself, which is what your code was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this code:**

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(YOUR_FUNCTION))`

hope this work for you